# How to show docstring or function signature in VS Code for a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code, docstring

I currently have installed VS Code as an alternative editor to Jupyterlab for Python Data Science development. Now I am wondering about how to show the docstring or signature of a function?

I didn't found anything about a shortcut oder a needed setting change.

Answer (score 3):

You can change these settings in your settings.json:

```
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },
```

[Docstring example of the print function while typing in a vscode jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzfDD.png)

Comment: what applies the change to settings? should I restart the notebook? the server?

Answer (score 2):

You can try CRLT + I. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

running

```
help(function_name)
```

is an alternative

Answer (score 0):

i installed

`python extension pack`

and that has intellicode in it and that solved mine

Comment: Welcome, please add some explanation